# EXCEL Add-in Windows to Apple conversion

Tags: excel, vba, macos, add-in

I developed an EXCEL VBA add-in in Windows. I have a user that uses both Microsoft and Apple. In Microsoft, my development environment, my add-in works perfectly.

When I copy the add-in to the Apple and use the insert - myadd-ins, no addins are listed and I don't see how to point/add the add-in.

Is there a special location I have to put my home made add-in for Apple? Does Apple add-ins have a different extension. Can I not create my own add-in on the Apple?

Thanks for all your assistance.

Comment: If you are using Excel 2011, then you will have to use the Excel 2003 way (xla) to create Add-Ins for MAC. For example `Set cbc = cb.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, temporary:=False)` and then `Set newitem = cbc.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)`

Comment: There are a significant number of differences between working with VBA on Windows and on Mac - file paths, and no COM on Mac are two of the bigger ones. It's not just a question of installation.

Comment: Thanks. After your comments and some research, I think to transition would be too long a process.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing several comments and doing some research, there does not seem to be an easy way to convert file. – Thanks for the thoughts.